# Configuring custom domain for Azure Web App

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I configured my custom domain to work with my Azure Web app and it's working but NOT with www.

So mydomain.com points to myapp.azurewebsites.net and it works but if I type www.mydomain.com, it gives me "Error 404 - Web App Not Found" error.

Here's what I have configured:

1. My domain is registered with GoDaddy and I have an A record pointing to the IP address I copied from my Azure Web App.
2. I also have a CNAME record awverify pointing to awverify.myapp.azurewebsites.net
3. I have my CNAME record pointing to myapp.azurewebsites.net
4. I then added mydomain.com and www.mydomain.com to the custom domains blade through the new Azure portal

Any idea I can pull up my web app using mydomain.com but NOT www.mydomain.com?

Comment: Either the hostname was not properly saved or your browser goes somewhere else. The first option can be verified by relaunching the portal and checking the settings for the site or using https://resources.azure.com/ and finding your site object there (and checking its hostnames). The second option might be because of TTL/hosts file etc. Try to do "ping myapp.azurewebsites.net" and "ping www.mydomain.com" and check whether you get the same IP address back.

Comment: In step 3 above, what is the *host* name of the CNAME record?  It should be *www*.

Answer (score 2):

Even though I entered the www.mydomain.com under custom domain under my web app's settings, for some reason it didn't save it which is why www was not working.